# document.activeElement returning a XULElement

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to get the focused element when the user press CTRL + SPACE on my Firefox add-on.

To do it, I thought to use the *document.activeElement* to get the focused element, but it is not working. It's always returning a XULElement.

I have just two files in this add-on:

Lib/main.js

```
var self = require ("sdk/self");

var workers = require("sdk/content/worker");
let worker =  workers.Worker({
                window: require("sdk/window/utils").getMostRecentBrowserWindow(),
                contentScriptFile: self.data.url("script.js")
              });


var { Hotkey } = require("sdk/hotkeys");
var showHotKey = Hotkey({
  combo: "control-space",
  onPress: function() {
        worker.port.emit ("getFocused", "");
  }
});
```

and the file Data/script.js

```
self.port.on ('getFocused', function (msg){
    var campo = document.activeElement;
    alert (campo);
});
```

(How you can see here: [Add-on SDK Builder Test Project](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/174775/latest/) )

So, can someone help me with it?

It's possible to get the input text or textarea from the XULElement and change its text?

Thank you very much!

------------------------ EDIT   ----------------------

I don't know if it helps, but, when the url text area (where we write the adress of the sites) has the focus, it returns a

*[object HTMLInputElement]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getMostRecentBrowserWindow` returns a ChromeWindow object. So it's normal that the activeElement` is a XUL element.

What you should do is

```
window: require("sdk/window/utils").getMostRecentBrowserWindow().gBrowser.contentWindow
```

Comment: Ok, nice. I'll test it and come back here to give you a feedback. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah!!!  It works! Thank you very very much! But I don't understand why it works... Can you give me some explanation or some link ?  Again, thank you!

Comment: Your target is the window containing the HTMLDocument of a web page. `getMostRecentBrowserWindow` returns the (front in case of many) window containing the root XULDocument of Firefox. The gBrowser property holds a reference to the `tabbrowser` element. And `contentWindow` holds a reference to the window of the selected tab (the only one that can accept input from the user). If you want to be extra safe, you should check if the document of this window is actually an HTMLDocument and possibly check the URl scheme too (about:home is an HTMLDocument but maybe you want to skip it).

Comment: Just a note: `require("sdk/window/utils").getMostRecentBrowserWindow().content` is shorter and not quite as Firefox-specific (the `window.content` variable is automatically being set to the window inside the main XUL frame).